unable to start any application after migration of an user per Migration Assistant
Could not open Menu items, nothing is selectable.
Reinstallation by using the recovery mod also can't be started,
because the button is grayed out. Mouse is moving, but clicking has no effect.
Fsck in singlemode was done with out errors.
System: macOS High Sierra
iMac 2011
There is no way to open any application. I can log in, the Desktop appears, but has no function. Moving the mouse over the dock, no reaction.
The imported user has Admin rights. he came from a system macOS 10.6
are there any plist files overwritten?
It looks like the System is locked.
Is there a way to reset the computer, using single mode?
All GUI system won't work.

Was it working correctly before you run Migration Assistant? Does the mouse work if you connect it to another computer?

If you can not boot to single user mode, you need the target disk mode or another bootable disk to use startup manager to start this Mac

All was perfekt working. After starting the Mig.Assistant I lost after one hour I the control of the application focus.  The Assistant was greyed to but transfers all data. Then he dosn't properly finish.

This is the nature of how things break - computers go so fast and one calculation can end progress on main threads

What about the mouse, does it work on another computer?

I used a Magic Mouse and a classical USB Mouse. Both are o.k. The problem that the OS dosen't offer something to click

I would recommend another Mac and target disk mode for your iMac to get the drive to a state where you can reinstall the OS and or remove the /var/db/.AppleSetupDone file and see if the OS is healthy enough to make a new admin user (choose a new short name like newadmin ).
Do you need to make a backup first?

What is the state of the drive, to reinstall the OS? The only way to use the System is the single mode.

I would use disk utility to repair the drive state and then proceed based on how critical it is to back up any files before they are lost or you erase the drive @Semmel

How can I make a backup, when all tools dosn't work. No really only wont to  get the  Computer functionally.

I can't start disk utility!

Yes - you need another Mac to run that via target disk mode I believe is your best option @Semmel

What I not understand is the fact, that the unusable GUI applications dosn't work in normal startup and in recovery mode. There must be an modification in recovery partition as also in macOS partition
